# OpenLayers 5.3 selected point feature does not return properties, but polygon does

Tags: openlayers, features, select, interaction

I am having some issues in OpenLayers 5.3.0. The context is that I'm using Sharepoint lists as a backend to save feature data and OpenLayers is running in a Vue.js container. Everything works as expected:

The geoJSON feature strings are pulled in from SharePoint and aggregated into a feature collection.
As I load each feature I add custom properties - most importantly the ItemID from the SharePoint list.
The features load on the map.
I can draw new features and save all of them.

If at any point I get all features with code like

```
allFeatures = self.drawLayer.getSource().getFeatures();
```

the features will contain the additional properties I have added.

The problem I am having is that when use a select interaction the selected feature comes back differently if it is a point or if it is a polygon - using for example:

```
self.drawClickSelect.on('select', function(e) {
            self.selectedFeatures = e.selected;                   
            console.log(self.selectedFeatures);
          });
```

The feature comes back with the added properties if it is a polygon, but if it's a point the properties itemID and modified do not exist.

Examples
Polygon returns:

```
e {…}
dispatching_: (...)
disposed_: (...)
geometryChangeKey_: (...)
geometryName_: (...)
id_: (...)
listeners_: (...)
ol_lm: (...)
ol_uid: (...)
pendingRemovals_: (...)
revision_: (...)
styleFunction_: (...)
style_: (...)
**values_: Object
geometry: e
itemID: 13
modified: false**
```

Point returns:

```
0: e
dispatching_: (...)
disposed_: (...)
geometryChangeKey_: (...)
geometryName_: (...)
id_: (...)
listeners_: (...)
ol_lm: (...)
ol_uid: (...)
pendingRemovals_: (...)
revision_: (...)
styleFunction_: (...)
style_: (...)
**values_: Object
geometry: (...)**
```

`self.drawLayer.getSource().getFeatures()` returns: (Note that the properties I'm interested are present for each feature.)

```
"{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-9148122.009657301,4148932.8076870437],[-9148001.336280514,4149124.4626323017],[-9148174.732892036,4149232.323163778],[-9148225.35521765,4149153.4073993675],[-9148302.20055545,4149200.6003566994],[-9148335.00415841,4149155.742857091],[-9148551.727115743,4149293.291205446],[-9148561.789387284,4149278.5208011325],[-9148673.828665541,4149349.3877884443],[-9148735.371373663,4149252.6485635266],[-9148560.38595463,4149144.0397318634],[-9148567.23964962,4149133.2237431305],[-9148549.761260215,4149122.8749220027],[-9148544.360359373,4149132.5307491873],[-9148449.959080853,4149071.7602422866],[-9148456.755445173,4149061.5738832294],[-9148442.091697177,4149052.313675927],[-9148435.004098615,4149063.0075244764],[-9148340.775473515,4149000.2413342204],[-9148324.546920547,4149028.1325729615],[-9148199.787204698,4148944.980097804],[-9148184.701774493,4148972.1811943417],[-9148122.009657301,4148932.8076870437]]]},"properties":{"itemID":12,"modified":false}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-9149230.727863472,4149974.6889362033],[-9148917.825374642,4149776.7721247915],[-9149008.484043097,4149633.442597651],[-9149321.386531925,4149831.359409064],[-9149230.727863472,4149974.6889362033]]]},"properties":{"itemID":13,"modified":false}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-9149507.058888558,4150498.531335066]},"properties":{"itemID":21,"modified":false}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-9149383.916618763,4150420.6414931556]},"properties":{"itemID":22,"modified":false}}]}"
```

Is there some known issue with points that would make them different than polygons with regard to properties?

Comment: Thank you for the formatting and cleanup TomazicM. I was a little slow on the uptake there.

Comment: The properties object of the geojson is included in the `value_` field but should be accessed using `.getProperties()`  (methods not documented in the API are usually not available when using minified builds)  What do you get when logging `self.selectedFeatures[0].getProperties()`

Comment: That returns the geometry only. I did find a workaround, but I'm curious as to why this would work.
`self.selectedFeatures = self.map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(e.mapBrowserEvent.pixel, function(feature) {
              return feature;
            });`
returns exactly what I'm after.

Comment: It seems sometimes like the object OL returns on select is a kind of copy of the original feature. And features seem to have different properties after they're added to a map than they do before. It's a bit confusing at times.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing this problem in the future I got to the bottom of it. The problem was that I was adding multiple interactions at the same time - i.e. Modify, Translate, and Select. 
I saw this issue only selecting points and lineStrings while all the interactions were active. If I only use the interactions one at a time (although Translate and Select seem to work ok together) I get back exactly what I expect. 
If it's documented somewhere that you shouldn't combine interactions I missed it.